# Store String in Subtrate by using Vec<u8>:

Tags: string

I want to store String value, some topics are using Vec, but I encounted this error: `error[E0599]: no function or associated item named 'max_encoded_len' found for struct 'Vec<u8>' in the current scope`

My code:

```
    #[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
    #[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
    #[codec(mel_bound())]
    pub struct BizAmount<T: Config> {
        pub amount: u32,
        pub price: Option<BalanceOf<T>>,
        pub organization: Organization,
        pub owner: AccountOf<T>,
    }

    #[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
    pub struct Organization {
        pub name: Vec<u8>,
        pub code: Vec<u8>,
    }
    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
```

I searched on google and not found any stuffs. Thank for your help!

Comment: Why store a string when you can store the hash of it? This puts a known limit on the amount of storage used for the variable. What is the use case for the contract needing to know the actual value of the string?

Comment: @forgetso I'm new so Substrate. What types I can use? thank you!

Comment: I've added an answer with  some more information

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to derive `MaxEncodedLen` for your `Organization`. This trait can only be implemented for types that have a maximum size defined at compile time. `Vec<u8>` does not have a fixed length because it can grow indefinitely at runtime.

The solution is to come up with a size limit (probably configured through your `Config` trait) and then use [`BoundedVec`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/bounded_vec/struct.BoundedVec.html) instead of `Vec`.

An example of that can be observed in the [uniques pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/f6679ddd31f68e9f1578064d58a246130c27026b/frame/uniques/src/lib.rs):

```rust
trait Config {
    type KeyLimit: Get<u32>;
}

pub fn set_attribute<T: Config>(
    key: BoundedVec<u8, T::KeyLimit>,
    value: BoundedVec<u8, T::ValueLimit>,
) -> DispatchResult {}
```

`BoundedVec` behaves like a `Vec` except that it takes a second type argument that defines the maximum size it can have. This argument needs to implement [`Get<u32>`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/trait.Get.html). `BoundedVec` will enforce this limit automatically and returns an `Err` when pushing new elements to it in case the limit is violated.

Comment: thank for your answer, can you show an example code or links, I tried but not work.

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: I encounted this error `error[E0277]: the trait bound '<T as pallet::Config>::KeyLimit: Clone' is not satisfied`

Comment: Another minimal example in the docs: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/proof-of-existence/#implement-pallet-events

Comment: BoundedVec does not work with many struct macros. Use arrays instead.

Answer (score 4):

It's generally bad practice to store a string in a smart contract

> In general, you should think twice if you really need String. Smart
> contracts usually don't use strings; those are typically used for user
> interactions and should live in your UI and not on the chain.
>
> Minimizing storage usage of your contract is a best practice and you
> should only persist items which you need to derive state transitions
> in your contract.
>
> If you still, for some reason, need to use String, then you should use
> the String from the ink! prelude.

[Source](https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/faq#how-do-i-use-string-in-my-contract)

It's quite unlikely that your smart contract will need to know the actual value of a string. Therefore, you can simply hash the string on the client side and then store the hash in the contract.

For example, in TypeScript before calling your contract function:

```
import { blake2AsU8a } from '@polkadot/util-crypto'
const theString = blake2AsU8a(argVal as unknown as string)
```

Then in the contract, store this value as a `Hash` type

```
the_string: Hash
```