# How to use Mapping with Sha2x256 in ink smart contracts

Tags: ink, rust, smart-contract, storage

I want to try and use Mapping with Sha2x256 or any other value that is large enough so that each of these will be unique.

I want mapping to be like this:
unique_ids: Mapping <Sha2x256 ,u128>

Whenever I try to make Mapping <String, u128> I get an error "contract doesn't have a size known at compile-time"

So I'm trying anything else that can act as an unique id and will not repeat itself. It can be Sha2x256, Blake2s256 etc.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `String` in `ink!` to store data because `String processing comes with a lot of overhead` and alternatively you can use `Vec<u8>` instead and if you really need `String` you can use `ink_prelude::String` [view the link](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_prelude/string/index.html). You can go through this [Question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-string-in-an-ink-smart-contract) for further details