# How to add and use a crate in an ink smart contract/ ink storage?

Tags: ink, rust

I want to use the [bytes](https://docs.rs/bytes/1.1.0/bytes/) crate in an ink! smart contract of mine.
Also I want to declare a Byte value in the ink_storage struct.
However, I cannot figure out how to do this.
After hours of trying and not finding a solution. Is there some documentation
which could help me, or a predefined way?

Comment: why do you need bytes crate specifically ? Can you provide additional details of what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to be able to store UTF8 values there .

Comment: You probably shouldn't store arbitrary length `utf8` for the same reasons [you shouldn't store arbitrary strings](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1155/380). You should try to minimise your contract storage costs by using hashes instead and then decode on the client side.

Comment: I don't want them to be of arbitrary length. I want them to be exactly 32 bytes or one byte. I will look into the Hash type option though, thank you. I'd still like to go how to go about with crates like that and ink! though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to store custom types in your smart contract as long as they meet all the right requirements.

For ink! this means that your type must at minimum implement the [`SpreadLayout`](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_storage/traits/trait.SpreadLayout.html)
and [`StorageLayout`](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_storage/traits/trait.StorageLayout.html) traits.

This gets slightly tricky when the type comes from an external crate due to Rust's Orphan Rules which don't let you implement foreign traits for foreign types.

One way to work around this is to create a wrapper type and implement the traits on that:

```rust
//! In your smart contract

use some_crate::SomeType;

// This is what you'll end up putting in your #[ink(storage)] struct
pub struct Wrapper(SomeType);

// Note, this may end up being hard to implement manually depending on the
// complexity of your type
impl SpreadLayout for Wrapper { ... }

// We only need this during metadata generation, which happens in an environment where we
// have access to the standard library and OS.
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
const _: () = {
    impl StorageLayout for Wrapper { ... }
};
```

Another, as Bruno mentioned, is to open a PR in the ink! repo and implement the traits
directly for that type.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that simple as ink! is an embedded Domain Specific Language (eDSL). Also note that ink! works in a `no_std` environment so not everything that is `std` is compatible. You can find the available ink! data structures in the [ink_prelude](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/crates/prelude/src/lib.rs) and in the [ink_prelude docs](https://docs.rs/ink_prelude/latest/ink_prelude/index.html) it clearly states:

> These definitions are useful since we are operating in a no_std environment and should be used by all ink! crates instead of directly using std or alloc crates. **If needed we shall instead enhance the exposed types here.**

So if you do see a use case for `Bytes` in ink! you can create an issue or PR in their repo to extend the ink! eDSL.

Also note that you can use vectors to store UTF-8 bytes:

- https://docs.rs/ink_prelude/latest/ink_prelude/vec/index.html

```rs
data: Vec<u8>
```