# How to use keccak256 sha256 in ink smart contracts?

Tags: ink, storage, hash

I want to hash string using sha256 and then store it inside of my ink smart contract.

I tested this code in Rust and it works out for me:

```
use crypto::sha2::Sha256;
use crypto::digest::Digest;

let phrase = "purchase hobby popular celery evil fantasy someone party position gossip host gather";
let mut seed = Sha256::new();
seed.input_str(&phrase);
let mut bytes = vec![0; seed.output_bytes()];
```

However, this code doesn't compile in ink, because ink can't seem to use crypto crate...

How can I use keccak256 inside of an ink smart contract to return me Vec ?

I found package Sha2x256, but I'm unsure how I should use this?

Comment: [In this questions](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1155/2844), he suggested to `Hash` `String` in client code and store that `Hash` in the contract.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ink_env::hash` [module](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/hash/index.html).

Then your hash function would look something like this

```
    use ink_env::hash;

    pub fn hash_keccak_256(input: &[u8]) -> [u8; 32] {
        let mut output = <hash::Keccak256 as hash::HashOutput>::Type::default();
        ink_env::hash_bytes::<hash::Keccak256>(input, &mut output);
        output
    }
```

`input` ofc is the bytes representation of the hashed value.

For ink! 4 replace `ink_env` with `ink::env`